# Issues with floating divs

Tags: css, web, css-float, html

I am trying to make a 3 column website but I cannot seem to get the right nav to display correctly.  It always displays below the other divs.  Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('images/background.png');
    background: no-repeat center center fix;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

p {
    margin: 0px;
    color: #231f20;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Garamond Premier Pro", serif;
    text-align: left;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    color: #231f20;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", sans serif;
}

#container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 750px;
}

#header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;
}

#marquee {
    width: 960px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #bc34ba;
    font-family: "Garamond Premier Pro", serif;
}

#topnav {
    border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: fed450;

#leftnav {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", sans serif;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: f58025;
    text-align: left;
    height: 580px;
}

#body {
    margin: 0px;
    border-right: 1px dashed #694717;
    width: 640px;
    height: 580px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    background-color: d80074;
}

#rightnav {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", sans serif;
    float: right;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: c1d82f;
    text-align: right;
    height: 580px;
}

#footer {
    width: 960px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="marquee"></div>
    <div id="topnav"></div>
    <div id="leftnav"></div>

    <div id="body">
        <h1>Title<h1>
        <br>
        <p>This is where the content is.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="rightnav"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is b/c you are separating them with the `body id` which does not float. You need to set three `div` columns and set the `widths` while `floating` them next to each other.

You also need to close your header tag:

```
</h1>
```

In your css you forgot the closing curly bracket `}` for `#topnav`

I found all these issues with just a quick glance. There could be more lingering.

Overall your code is a mess and you should consider studying HTML and CSS a bit more.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. As you can probably guess, this is my first website and I understand it can definitely use work.

Comment: Oh no problem at all. We all was in the same spot you are. The best way to learn is through trial and error :) Hang in there and in no time it will be second nature to you.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `#` symbol in front of all your `backgroud-color:` values. Give the proper `width` to all three columns. `float: left` on `#body` and `#rightnav`, assuming you want `#leftnav`, `#body`, `#rightnav`. Also, close `#topnav` with `}`.

Comment: Very funny. As you can probably guess this is my first website so I will try to work on my color scheme and layout.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Chris78](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491130/chris78) is right that you are missing the closing `}` on the `#topnav` ruleset. You should also move the `#rightnav` div to come before the the `#body` div.

You may want to consider using a grid solution for your layout. Here is [just one example](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki/Grids)